# Unprotect or remove Bloomberg BbgResearchPubStorageWorksheet in Excel workbook

Tags: excel, bloomberg

Excel workbooks that have used the Bloomberg Add-In contain a hidden protected sheet called `BbgResearchPubStorageWorksheet`.  The fact that sheet is protected prevents certain functions from being performed on the workbook – e.g., deleting custom styles.  How can that worksheet be unprotected or removed from the workbook?

Unprotecting from the File >> Info menu claims to require a password, as shown in this screenshot:
[image: Password required to unprotect BbgResearchPubStorageWorksheet]

(So far nobody in Bloomberg support has admitted that they have anything to do with this worksheet, so they can't provide the password to unprotect it.)

`BbgResearchPubStorageWorksheet` also appears in the Excel Objects list, but cannot be removed from the VBA editor:

[image: VBA editor showing hidden Bloomberg worksheet]

How can we unprotect or remove this `BbgResearchPubStorageWorksheet`?

(One kludge would be to copy everything else in the workbook into a new workbook, but for a complicated workbook is becomes very tricky to preserve all references, names, and VB code in that process.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First expose the sheet by going to its properties in the VBA editor and changing its Visible property from `xlSheetVeryHidden` to `xlSheetVisible`:

[image: xlSheetVeryHidden property]

Now the worksheet will be visible and it can be deleted, even without knowing the password that was applied to protect it.